# Expandable/Collapsable file tree in excel

Tags: excel

Is there any way to make an expandable/collapsable file menu tree in excel, one that mimics windows explorer? somthing like this: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/phpFileTree/demo/demo_classic.php

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the context? Why do you want a file tree in Excel?

Comment: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?194-Using-a-Treeview-Control